# Bind9 configuration

Tags: dns

I can't understand why my dns server won't work.
i get this, when i testing with "dig"

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> connectioon.eu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 54973
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;connectioon.eu.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.33#53(192.168.1.33)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec  9 20:14:07 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

named.conf.local:

```
zone "connectioon.eu" {
    type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/connectioon.eu";
};

zone "21.100.91.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/192.168.1";
};





I have tried with:

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/192.168.1";
};

and

zone "192.168.1.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/192.168.1";
};
```

the connectioon.eu conf file:

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA    connectioon.eu. voice12345678910.hotmail.com. (
         09122011180545     ; Serial
                       604800   ; Refresh
                         86400  ; Retry
                    2419200 ; Expire
                     604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  connectioon.eu.
@   IN  91.100.21.28

the 192.168.1 file:
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA     connectioon.eu. voice12345678910.hotmail.com. (
         09122011184553     ; Serial
                       604800   ; Refresh
                         86400  ; Retry
                    2419200 ; Expire
                    604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
    NS  connectioon.eu.
28  PTR connectioon.eu.
```

my public ip is: **91.100.21.28** and local ip to dns: **192.168.1.33**

ps. i using bind9 on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: This would be a better question for http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

This command :

```
dig connectioon.eu @91.100.21.28
```

shows

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> connectioon.eu @91.100.21.28
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Are you sure a name server is listening on port 53 (and is not restricted to local requests) ?
I assume 91.100.21.28 is where your DNS server is meant to be.

*(edit: Actually a quick `dig connectioon.eu +norecurse @x.nic.eu` shows that the primary NS is `91.100.21.28.hostname-generic.arrownet.dk` which resolves to 91.100.21.28)*

PS: +1 for ziesemer's serverfault-related comment